# Get 'src' value of an image from html source code (response) under particular header (ex: Most popular) using Jmeter xpath extractor

Tags: jmeter

Get 'src' value of an image from html source code (response) under particular header (ex: Most popular) using Jmeter xpath extractor.

When tried xpath extractor post processor under http request, able to fetch all the 'src' values of all images available on the page. However if want to get particular image under header () /sub heading, how to processed. Please guide.

Working one (xpath extractor) to get all the image's src:
`//img[@class="img-re"]/@src`

The web page has sections like:
Most popular
Recently viewed

Now need to get image src of Most popular section and the html response looks like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js">
<head>
xxx
<div id="books">    
 <div id="booksGrid" class="books"
  <div class = "row"> ==$0
  <div class="book">
   <a href="/hyperlink">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://example.com/32434.jpg">
    <p class ="title">...</p>
  </a>
  </div>
<h3> Releases </h3>
<div id="igdrec_1" class="row">
 <div class="book">
  <a onclik="gaSend...>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="https://example.com/4355636.jpg">
  </a>
  </div>
```

Please guide how to extract this using jmeter.

Comment: More lines of response, please so we could see the markup of at least 2 sections

Comment: @DmitriT Thanks for the reply. I have added more markup, please guide.